# Derived Category in terms of Torsion Theory?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, intuition, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

It is known that there's a bijection between hereditary torsion theories on, and localizations of, a fixed abelian category.

- Is this bijection natural? How/why not?
- How can I think of the derived category in terms of a hereditary torsion theory and vice-versa?
- Where can I find discussions of this (not just formalism)?

Comment: There are two senses of "localisation" here. The derived category does _not_ come from a torsion theory.

Comment: @ZhenLin could you elaborate? What senses of localization?

Comment: If you go read the relevant definitions of "localisation" in the two contexts you will realise they are not the same.

Comment: Have you tried looking to "Homotopical and homological aspects of torsion"?